# Python lxml.html linebreaks?

Tags: python, lxml

Im using lxml.html.cleaner to clean html from an input text.  how can i change `\n` to `<br />` in lxml.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly easy, slightly hacky way: You could do this as part of a two step process, assuming you have used `lxml.html.parse` or whichever method to build DOM.

1. iterate through the text and tail attributes of the nodes with string replacements. Look at the `iterdescendants` method, which walks through everything for you.
2. `lxml.html.clean` as per normal

A more complex way would be to monkey patch the [`lxml.html.clean`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/api/lxml.html.clean-pysrc.html) module. Unlike lots of `lxml`, this module is written in Python and is fairly accessible. For example, there is currently a [`_substitute_whitespace`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/api/lxml.html.clean-pysrc.html#_substitute_whitespace) function.